# Breakout Program only shows 1 Brick

Tags: java

To be frank i have not the slightest clue how to fix this whats so ever. It works until you get to the part that only 1 brick shows and its kinda frustrating... If anyone could help me i would appreciate it. I did look up how to fix this but i didn't even find anyone that had this problem. Google searching isn't really that good. Oh and i used Eclipse for this program.

**Board Class**

```
package Final;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel implements Commons {



    private Timer timer;
    private String message = "Your Fired";
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle paddle;
    private Brick bricks[];
    private boolean ingame = true;

    public Board() {

        initBoard();
    }

    private void initBoard() {

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);

        bricks = new Brick[N_OF_BRICKS];
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), DELAY, PERIOD);
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {

        super.addNotify();
        gameInit();
    }

    private void gameInit() {

        ball = new Ball();
        paddle = new Paddle();

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                bricks[k] = new Brick(j * 40 + 30, i * 10 + 50);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        if (ingame) {

            drawObjects(g2d);
        } else {

            gameFinished(g2d);
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private void drawObjects(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(),
                paddle.getWidth(), paddle.getHeight(), this);

        for (int i = 0; i < N_OF_BRICKS; i++) {
            if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
                g2d.drawImage(bricks[i].getImage(), bricks[i].getX(),
                        bricks[i].getY(), bricks[i].getWidth(),
                        bricks[i].getHeight(), this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void gameFinished(Graphics2D g2d) {

        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18);
        FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(font);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(message,
                (Commons.WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(message)) / 2,
                Commons.WIDTH / 2);
    }
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }

    private class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ball.move();
            paddle.move();
            checkCollision();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private void stopGame() {

        ingame = false;
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private void checkCollision() {

        if (ball.getRect().getMaxY() > Commons.BOTTOM_EDGE) {
            stopGame();
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N_OF_BRICKS; i++) {

            if (bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
                j++;
            }

            if (j == N_OF_BRICKS) {
                message = "Pay Day";
                stopGame();
            }
        }

        if ((ball.getRect()).intersects(paddle.getRect())) {

            int paddleLPos = (int) paddle.getRect().getMinX();
            int ballLPos = (int) ball.getRect().getMinX();

            int first = paddleLPos + 8;
            int second = paddleLPos + 16;
            int third = paddleLPos + 24;
            int fourth = paddleLPos + 32;

            if (ballLPos < first) {
                ball.setXDir(-1);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }

            if (ballLPos >= first && ballLPos < second) {
                ball.setXDir(-1);
                ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
            }

            if (ballLPos >= second && ballLPos < third) {
                ball.setXDir(0);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }

            if (ballLPos >= third && ballLPos < fourth) {
                ball.setXDir(1);
                ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
            }

            if (ballLPos > fourth) {
                ball.setXDir(1);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N_OF_BRICKS; i++) {

            if ((ball.getRect()).intersects(bricks[i].getRect())) {

                int ballLeft = (int) ball.getRect().getMinX();
                int ballHeight = (int) ball.getRect().getHeight();
                int ballWidth = (int) ball.getRect().getWidth();
                int ballTop = (int) ball.getRect().getMinY();

                Point pointRight = new Point(ballLeft + ballWidth + 1, ballTop);
                Point pointLeft = new Point(ballLeft - 1, ballTop);
                Point pointTop = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop - 1);
                Point pointBottom = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop + ballHeight + 1);

                if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
                    if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointRight)) {
                        ball.setXDir(-1);
                    } else if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointLeft)) {
                        ball.setXDir(1);
                    }

                    if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointTop)) {
                        ball.setYDir(1);
                    } else if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointBottom)) {
                        ball.setYDir(-1);
                    }

                    bricks[i].setDestroyed(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Brick Class**

```
package Final;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Brick extends Sprite {

    private boolean destroyed;

    public Brick(int x, int y) {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("images/bricks.png");
        image = ii.getImage();

        i_width = image.getWidth(null);
        i_heigth = image.getHeight(null);

        destroyed = false;
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed() {

        return destroyed;
    }

    public void setDestroyed(boolean val) {

        destroyed = val;
    }
}
```

**Commons Class**

```
package Final;

    public interface Commons {

        public static final int WIDTH = 300;
        public static final int HEIGTH = 400;
        public static final int BOTTOM_EDGE = 390;
        public static final int N_OF_BRICKS = 30;
        public static final int INIT_PADDLE_X = 200;
        public static final int INIT_PADDLE_Y = 360;
        public static final int INIT_BALL_X = 230;
        public static final int INIT_BALL_Y = 355;    
        public static final int DELAY = 1000;
        public static final int PERIOD = 10;
    }
```

**Sprite Class**

```
package Final;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Sprite {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int i_width;
    protected int i_heigth;
    protected Image image;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return i_width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return i_heigth;
    }

    Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    Rectangle getRect() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y,
                image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

**Breakout Class**

```
package Final;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Breakout extends JFrame {



    public Breakout() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Lord Carl's Demolition Job");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(Commons.WIDTH, Commons.HEIGTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                Breakout game = new Breakout();
                game.setVisible(true);                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript

Comment: Debug your program please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `checkCollision()`. Inside the loop, `j` will never equal `N_OF_BRICKS` because of the loop condition. You could change to:

```
private void checkCollision() {

    if (ball.getRect().getMaxY() > Commons.BOTTOM_EDGE) {
        stopGame();
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_OF_BRICKS; i++) {

        if (bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (j == N_OF_BRICKS) {
        message = "Pay Day";
        stopGame();
    }
}
```

Also, in the `Brick` class you neglect to store the x,y coords:

```
public class Brick extends Sprite {
    ....
    public Brick(int x, int y) {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("images/bricks.png");
        image = ii.getImage();

        i_width = image.getWidth(null);
        i_heigth = image.getHeight(null);

        destroyed = false;

        // Save these
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }
    ....
}
```

Or, add a constructor to the `Sprite` class and call that from the `Brick` constructor:

```
public class Sprite {
    ....
    public Sprite(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }
    ....
}

    public class Brick extends Sprite {
        ....
        public Brick(int x, int y) {
            // Call the sprite constructor
            super(x, y);

            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("images/bricks.png");
            image = ii.getImage();

            i_width = image.getWidth(null);
            i_heigth = image.getHeight(null);

            destroyed = false;
        }
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Well the same thing still happens. Only one brick appears. Like the game will run and the paddle and ball appear but only 1 brick appears instead of 30.

Comment: @ChristianFigueroa It sounds like you are describing a different issue. Your question was about the final brick. Now you are saying when you start the game, only one brick appears?

Comment: Of course i screw up the question.. Anyways i dont lnow what to do im in High School programing and it took me forever to wrap my head around this. What my question is why its only printing one brick instead of 30 because i cant find what i did wrong.

Comment: @ChristianFigueroa In the `Brick` constructor, you ignore the `x` and `y` parameters. You need to save them: `this.x = x; this.y = y;` Otherwise, all bricks will have (0,0) coordinates. So all 30 are being drawn, just on top of one another.

Comment: How would i do that.

Comment: I know it says not to say thanks but seriously thank you so much.